# Json string value doesn't give all data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

Here's my json string

```
{
  "tracking_information": {
    "status_name": "Picked", 
    "status_code": "PCK", 
    "status_date": "2017-11-12T07:28:01.123272", 
    "source": "Web", 
    "status_date_local": "2017-11-12 11:28:01", 
    "status_description": "Picked up"
  }, 
  "order_information": {
    "tracking_no": "34120022", 
    "so_number": "44", 
    "client_ref": "Test Order"
  }
}
```

this is my code

```
byte[] json_orders = wc.DownloadData(url);

var bytesAsString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(json_orders);

dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bytesAsString);
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.tracking_information)
{
    string track_info = obj.Value;
}
```

The obj variable holds only status name value.  how can I get the status code and associated information.

Comment: As I can test it, you get all the data in the _tracking_information_ section. Just add a _Console.WriteLine(obj.Value)_ inside the loop and look at the result

Comment: @Steve I want to get the values one time.  I only want to check the value of the object

Comment: BTW it is very unusual to get an ASCII encoded JSON result from a webservice. You should have a closer look again. I would expect UTF8 encoding

Comment: Is there a reason you are deserializing to dynamic (vs a concrete type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no required for loop. Just try like that;

```
var statusCode = jsonObj.tracking_information.status_code
var statusName= jsonObj.tracking_information.status_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already there your problem with the way your retrieve it,
you can always your quick watch to examine all object information.

[image]